# List<T>().Add problem C#

Tags: c#, list

I made a List to hold object in it, and then i'll read it. But even if i give an index to List, i always get the same object results. Here is the code:

```
            List<TempIds> treeDIds = new List<TempIds>();
            TempIds tempIds = new TempIds();


            foreach (ItemGroupTreeD treeD in itemTreeDColl)
            {

                //Idleri listeye alıyoruz daha sonra karşılaştırma yapmak için
                tempIds.TreeDId = treeD.Id;
                tempIds.TreeParentId = treeD.TreeParentId;
                treeDIds.Insert(treeDIds.Count, tempIds);
                //----

                //Eğer ilk gelen detay id ile methoda gelen id bir ise collectiona ekliyoruz.
                if (tempIds.TreeDId == groupTreeDId)
                {
                    treeDTempColl.Add(treeD);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Burada karşılaştırma yapıyoruz.
                    for (int i = 0; i < treeDIds.Count; i++)
                    {
                        if (tempIds.TreeParentId == treeDIds[i].TreeDId)
                        {
                            treeDTempColl.Add(treeD);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

For example:

For the first loop TreeDId = 3 and TreeParentId = 1 then i insert them index 0. second loop TreeDId = 2, TreeParentId = 1, then insert them index 1. When loop into the List, i always get TreeDId = 2 and TreeParentId = 1, because the last loop is the second loop. What else i can do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is only 1 tempIds object. the item in the list is the same one, and has the last item in it.
move the `TempIds tempIds = new TempIds();` into the loop

```
        foreach (ItemGroupTreeD treeD in itemTreeDColl)
        {
          TempIds tempIds = new TempIds();
```

Remember that a list doesn't contain copies of the data you add. It contains a reference to the object you've added. Doing it this way create a new object for you to insert every time.

Comment: Thats a possibility too, didn't think of that

Answer (score 0):

I think, You are modifying the same object within a loop. Since the list is just holding references to the same object, you will see the same object at all indexes.

You need to move `var tempIds =new TempIds();` within the foreach block

and optionally use `treeDIds.Add(tempIds);` instead of `treeDIds.Insert(treeDIds.Count, tempIds);`

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the same `object reference` more than once. Your class `TempIds` and `ItemGroupTreeD`, If possible, should be made a struct, and just add the object, or make  them inherit from `IClonable` and then add a Clone of the object.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reinstantiate `tempIds` in your foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting same reference all over again.  Either `Clone()` it or move its creation inside the loop.